# how to find <import> tag in .csproj file?

Tags: c#

I am using visual c# 2010 Express and I am to use stylecop. I read article on http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20in%20VS2005%20or%20VS%20Express.

I am unable to find `<import>` tag. Within the csproj file, how to find the import tag which imports the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file,

and how to insert a new import to link to the StyleCop.Targets file

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> 
<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\Microsoft\StyleCop\v4.4\StyleCop.targets"/>
```

If any one find please help me on this.

Comment: Open csproj with notepad and at the end of file you shoud find it

Comment: just open the csproj file in wordpad or notepad and search for import

Comment: yes I tried I am getting only 1 line that too <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" />

Comment: show screen shot of your project...something is wrong here

Comment: I installed stylecop and inserted <import> tag in myproj.csproj file, when I open myproj it is giving errror message that the path which is specified in <import> tag was not found

Answer (score 1):

In the Solution Explorer:

- Right click on your project, select `Unload project`.
- Right click on the project again and select `Edit project`.
- .csproj file will be open as XML.
- After you are done editing the file, right click on the project and select `Reload Project`.

Comment: I am not getting option like Unload project after right clicking on project.

Comment: Hmm... weird. Try just opening csproj file with notepad then.

Comment: yes I opened but I am getting <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" />

Comment: Look for `<Import>` tag, should be somewhere in the end of the file.

Comment: why I am not getting Unload project option

Comment: Did you do it in Solution Explorer? or just Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

On your windows explorer,

- right click on the project file and
- select **open with**
- select **notepad**

there it solves your problem

Comment: I done that but I am getting <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" /> only

Answer (score 0):

You mention only the `Project` tag is used. The `Import` property is a child of project, so you should be able to do this (taken from the `StyleCop` website you linked)

Note that the project tag was opened "`/>` becomes `>`" and a closing `</project>` is added.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(STYLECOPTOOLS)\v4.4\StyleCop.Targets" />
</Project>
```